# Flask serves static files with different path after forward slash

Tags: flask, routes

I'm trying to access a page using Flask but static files are not served.

```
@app.route('/hello/', 
methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello:
    return render_template('hello.html')
```

I get the page hello.html on the browser but all static files path have changed to *localhost:5000/hello/static...*
But if I change to:

```
@app.route('/hello')
```

The static files are served correctly.
So whenever I have any route that has a forward slash, it changes the static files being served i.e

```
@app.route('/editFile/<int:id>')
```

Static files would change and be served under new path **localhost:5000/editFile/static/...**
[Routes with / after makes all static files be searched with wrong paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua591.png)

[If no / is added after route then static files are loaded correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7SEP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend a slash to those routes:

```
@app.route('/hello')
```

and:

```
@app.route('/editFile/<int:id>')
```

This should give the expected behaviour.

As a side-note, if you also add a trailing slash, for example:

```
@app.route('/test/')
```

Then a request to `/test/` will return the response, and a request to `/test` will return a 308 redirect to `/test/`:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5009/test/  
response%

$ curl -i http://localhost:5000/test
HTTP/1.0 308 PERMANENT REDIRECT
Location: http://localhost:5000/test/

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL:
<a href="http://localhost:5009/test/">http://localhost:5000/test/</a>.  If not click the link.%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the slash after the route like this `/hello/` then when you are accessing the static file you should use this `url_for('static',filename = 'file')`
The static endpoint is used to retrieve the static files

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a file in the static folder, include a leading '/' in the href for locating the file, i.e. href="/static/filename".  The behavior observed in the parent post occurs when the leading slash is omitted, i.e. href="static/filename"